# I want to select multiple products using a checkbox and add to the cart all in a single click

Tags: cart, addtocart, multiple-add-to-cart

Is there anything out in the marketplace like this already? I'm willing to put in the work to build the solution but thought I'd check here for some pre-existing module or partial code I could use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

BSS has this plugin

https://bsscommerce.com/magento-2-add-multiple-products-to-cart-extension.html

The plugin matches your requirement. Do one thing don't directly buy it. First, contact them via email and ask for a discount. I am sure they will provide some coupon codes for checkout. (They had given us in the past)